# Realm Insert NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, realm

While inserting List to Realm  `NullPointerException` thrown. 
Please help me anyone.

Can you suggest me for best practice in Realm DB Management in Android

My Code:

```
public class DrinksFragment
        extends Fragment {

    private Realm realm;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_drinks, container, false);
        Realm.init(getActivity());
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        return view;
    }

    public boolean drinksToDB(final List<ProductModel> productModel) {
        realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm bgrealm) {
                RealmList<ProductModel> realproductList = new RealmList<>();
                realproductList.addAll(productModel);
            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Log.d("REALM_DB_INSERT", "Data Inserted");
            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable error) {
                Log.d("REALM_DB_INSERT", error.getMessage());
            }
        });

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Noise Generator. You making very bad noise. Please Read this question fully then Mark it

Comment: You should really learn what an NPE is and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advice you to do something like this:

First of all init Realm immediately only once when you open your app:

```
public class StartApplication
            extends Application {

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            Realm.init(getApplicationContext());
        }
}
```

And then you can get the realm object in this way everywhere:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
```

Comment: Yes i'm Already done In Application Class

Comment: @NatheemYousuf so you don't have to write Realm.init(getActivity()); in your Fragment. Remove that line.

Comment: No Luck @Curio                                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'io.realm.RealmAsyncTask io.realm.Realm.executeTransactionAsync(io.realm.Realm$Transaction, io.realm.Realm$Transaction$OnSuccess, io.realm.Realm$Transaction$OnError)' on a null object reference

Comment: @NatheemYousuf when do you call drinksToDB method?